# How can I define a Given statements in Cucumber using other When statements?

Tags: cucumber, cypress

I’ve been using Cucumber with Cypress a lot lately (actually writing a framework: picklejs.com). I’m in love with defining everything using plain English.

However I can’t seem to find a way to define my Given statements using other When statements. I can only programmatically define it.

Any thoughts on how to make this possible?

Ex

```
GivenDef: I do 2 actions 
    When I do action 1
    And I do action 2

Scenario: I do 3 actions 
    Given I do 2 actions
    When I do action 3
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to call a scenario from another scenario. That is not supported in Gherkin. And it is not likely to be supported either as this leads to using Gherkin as a programming language.

So how is this achieved then? Express your scenarios at a higher abstraction level. This higher level scenario would delegate to one, or many, helper libraries when the steps are executed. Pretty much as @joshua-wade suggests.

Is it backwards? It depends on your perspective. If Gherkin is used as a programming language for specifying tests, it might seem backwards. If Gherkin is a way to record examples of how your system should be used in the language of the business, it is not so backwards. At least not in my opinion.

Comment: Right, but imagine it from a PM perspective: you have a sequence that you do very often. ex: "Add Item to cart, set quantity to 3, set color to red". The PM would either have to repeat those 3 phrases over and over making the definition unnreadable OR bother a Developer to make a programatic sequence. Wouldn't it be easier for them to define the sequence themselves in a block and then call it as a simple `When`?

Comment: I'd like to look into how to add a "Scenario" block to the syntax and see how they like it. I assume I should fork this, right? https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/tree/master/cucumber-expressions/javascript/src

Answer (score 0):

As purely a Gherkin question, I don't believe what you're asking is directly possible. It's one of the limitations of Gherkin as a way of defining tests.

I have seen it suggested to build a helper library for test functionality and calling those external functions in your step definitions. That way, you could do something like this:

Gherkin:

```
Scenario: I do 3 actions
    Given I do 2 actions
    When I do action 3
```

Step definition:

```
Given("I do 2 actions", () => {
    action1();
    action2();
});

When("I do action 3", () => {
    action3();
});
```

Helper library:

```
let action1 = () => {
    // ...
};
let action2 = () => {
    // ...
};
let action3 = () => {
    // ...
};
```

My apologies if the code isn't completely accurate. I've only used Cucumber in Ruby.

Comment: Yeah that’s what I’ve been doing so far. It just seems kind of backwards to define sequences programmatically when the entire point of cucumber is to enable plain English definitions. My goal is to get our PMs to write all our tests. Which would include sequences. I predefined all the sentences they need in pickle.